# Online text editor that saves to server

Tags: html

What I have been trying to do for some time is to create a basic (online) text editor that saves files on to the web server.

So far I have had no luck mostly because a lot of examples seem to use a PHP uploader script to save the file and the web hosting service I use seems to have their PHP set up to not allow uploads and there is no way I can change this.

So after no luck elsewhere I decided to see what suggestions you might have. Any suggestions as to what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Find another host. Are you using a free host by any chance? Considering how cheap they are these days (I pay £30ish per year, which is totally worth it as a playground for me), you should invest!